# I am getting " [onTurnError]: StatusCodeError: 404 - undefined" error on running a dialog calling QnA Maker in Microsoft Bot Framework SDK4 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to call the QnA Maker through a Dialog I have created. I have created a qnamaker object in the Dialog and want pass the users answer to a prompt(from the previous step) into the getAnswers() method of QnAMaker. But the response of getAnswers() simply returns "[onTurnError]: StatusCodeError: 404 - undefined".

I am testing the bot locally on Bot Emulator. I have created the KnowledgeBase on qnamaker.ai and added the QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey, QnAEndpointHostName to the .env file. I am calling the QnADialog from another dialog (mainDialog).

Kindly help me out! Thanks!

Here is the code for the QnADialog that I have created, It has a waterafall Dialog containing 2 steps. The first step (initialStep) prompts the user for a query, the second step calls the qnamaker.getAnswers(step.context) - to which I have passed step.context. I have already included the QnAMaker using botbuilder-ai.

```
class QnADialog extends ComponentDialog{
    constructor(id){
        super(id||QNA_DIALOG);

        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(ASK_QUERY_PROMPT))
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.initialStep.bind(this), 
            this.callQnAMakerStep.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;

        try {
           this.qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
                knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
                endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
                host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`QnAMaker Exception: ${ err } Check your QnAMaker configuration in .env`);
        }

    }

    async initialStep(step){
        console.log("QnADialog.initialStep :")
        await step.context.sendActivity("Hello testing!");
        return step.prompt(ASK_QUERY_PROMPT, 'Ask any query you have...');
    }

    async callQnAMakerStep(step){
        var query = step.result;
        console.log("qnaDialog.callQnAMakerStep calling QnA Maker...");

        const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(step.context);
        console.log("qnaResult is : "+ qnaResult);

        // If an answer was received from QnA Maker, send the answer back to the user.
        if (qnaResults[0]) {
            await step.context.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);

        // If no answers were returned from QnA Maker, reply with help.
        } else {
            await step.context.sendActivity('No QnA Maker answers were     found.');
        }

        return await step.endDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm this sounds like a URL problem. Double check that your knowledge base is published (for what you’ve said it sounds like it is). Failing that I would make sure that the value you are providing for QnAEndpointHostName is the host name part of the following URL, not the entire URL ‘https://{hostname}.azurewebsites.net’ as per the [troubleshooting documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/troubleshooting-runtime#how-to-get-the-qnamaker-service-hostname).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had put the QnAAuthKey wrong!